# Backbone.js: calling custom events inside a View?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I would like to update part of my view when the user types into a input field. Initially I bound to the `keyup` event listener within the View's `events` field, and that worked well:

```
window.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
 el: $("#myapp"),
 events: {
   "keyup #myInput": "updateSpan",
 }, ...
 updateSpan: function() { 
     this.span.text(this.input.val());
 }, ...
});
```

But then I realised that `keyup` updated too often and made the app slow. So I decided to use the [typeWatch plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/TypeWatch) so the event would only fire the user stopped typing. But now I don't know how to set the custom event listener in Backbone. Currently I have this:

```
window.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
 initialize: { 
  var options = {
      callback: function(){ 
        alert('event fired'); 
        this.updateSpan; 
      },
      wait:750
  }
  this.input.typeWatch(options);
 }, ...
 updateSpan: function() { 
     this.span.text(this.input.val());
 }, ...
});
```

Two questions:

1. I see the alert, but `updateSpan` is not being fired. I think I'm using `this` incorrectly in the callback, but how should I do it?
2. Is `initialize` now the right place to set the typeWatch event listener, or can I continue to use the `events` field as I did before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't actually calling `updateSpan`, and you're right that `this` wont be the correct thing. Easiest way to solve it is to just capture the view into another variable first:

```
  var v = this;
  var options = {
    callback: function() {
      alert('event fired');
      v.updateSpan();
    },
    wait: 750
  };
  this.input.typeWatch(options);
```

As for your second question, usually I will attach functionality like this in `initialize` if it's on the base element and in `render` if it's not, so I think in this case you've probably got it right.